# Generate j2me netbeans project from lwuit resource editor error

Tags: lwuit-resource-editor

hi i tried to generate netbeans project from lwuit 1.5 resource editor but it give me an error that say:

> Problem: The project uses the Java Platform called "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC", but this platform was not found.
>   Solution: Click Resolve and create new platform called "Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC".

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Open the Netbeans IDE 7.x.x

2- Select : Tools, Java platforms, Click on the folder J2ME

3- Click on the "Add Platform" button

4- Select Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator, and "next"

5- The platform "C:\WTK2.5.2_01" will be automatically detected. Select it, and click "next"

6- At the tab "Description", in the textfield "Platform Name", write exactly the name: Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC